# jQuery keyup() on Visual editor (TinyMCE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tinymce

Wordpress is using TinyMCE editor for visual editor.

I want to hook typing in this editor. I have this code:

```
 tinyMCE.activeEditor.onKeyUp.add(function(ed, e) {
     console.debug(
         tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'})
     )
 });
```

This is working, but I am getting error if Editor is not active in the moment when page is loaded and I am getting message "Deprecated TinyMCE API call: .onKeyPress.add(..)"

What is the best code to hook typing in this editor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using V4 of tinymce, the binding of events has changed since V3. The new way to bind events is

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.on('keyup', function(ed, e) {
   console.debug(
     tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'});
    );
});
```

See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PalinDrome555/ff5appye/)

Answer (score 0):

To add an event listener to an element you need to select it properly first.

For example:
`<textarea id="visual_editor_selector"></textarea>`

In JQuery, the id attribute is called with a #, like:

```
$('#visual_editor_selector')
```

Comment: I know that, this was just an examle, I will edit my question